# Populate tableview from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an NSDictionary received from a json request that looks like this:

```
RESULT : (
    {
    Id1 = 138;
    lat = "45.5292910";
    long = "-73.6241500";
    order = "2343YY3"

},
    {
    Id1 = 137;
    lat = "45.5292910";
    long = "-73.6241500";
    order = "2343YY3"

}, etc.
```

I want to display it in a TableView (CellforRowAtIndexPath), so I obtain the data as NSArray. The method seems inefficient as each key `Id1`, `lat`, `long`, etc is created as an NSArray so that I can display them each with: `[self.data1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` `[self.data2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`, etc.

How can I achieve the same thing without creating and using 4 NSArrays? Can I use a single NSArray or the NSMutableDictionary which stores the data?

UPDATED:

When the TableView loads, it is initially empty but I have a button on that same VC that loads a modal view of a form. When I load the form and then dismiss it returning to the TableView, the data is LOADED! Could you suggest what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use a single array.  The trick is to create an array with each array entry holding a dictionary.  Then you query the array to populate your tableview.

E.g.: If your array is a property called `tableData` and you have custom tableview cell called `CustomCell` then your code might look something like the following:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.latitude.text = [[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"lat"];
    cell.longitude.text = [[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"long"];
    // continue configuration etc..
    return cell;
}
```

Similarly, if you have multiple sections in your tableview then you will construct an array of arrays, with each sub-array containing the dictionaries for that section. The code to populate the tableview would look something similar to the following:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [self.tableData count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [[self.tableData objectAtIndex:section] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    // Configure the cell...
    cell.latitude.text = [[[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"lat"];
    cell.longitude.text = [[[self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"long"];
    // continue configuration etc..
    return cell;
}
```

TL;DR; Take your dictionaries created from your JSON data and put them in an array.  Then query the array to populate the tableview.

Comment: I am running into a problem in tableView: numberOfRowsInSection: when I do [self.results count] as it always returns 0, would you know why because that is strange? When I NSLog the count just after self.results = [myDictionary valueForKey:@"result"]; where results is my NSArray it gives me the correct number of 25 but in that method it is 0. The table is frozen at that point. Also, I am subclassing the tableviewcell which works well because I have two of such similar designs and the other works well. I appreciate your help and I am looking out for your advice.

Comment: If [self.results count] returns zero (at any point) then there are no values in the array (at that point).  The code loading the array may have an error in it or you may be overwriting the array.  Firstly, check that the property is declared `(strong, copy)`. Secondly, try stepping through the code in the debugger checking the data at each step.

Comment: thanks a lot! I made some progress but I have ONE more piece of the puzzle. If you think I should make a new question, let me know. When the tableview loads, it is initially empty but I have a button on that same VC that loads a modal view of a form. When I load the form and then dismiss it returning to the tableview, the data is LOADED! Could you suggest what I am missing?

Comment: @Paulo: Definitely sounds like a new question.  Post it with some more details to StackOverflow so that more people can view it and assist.  But it sounds like your array `self.results` is not available on first load. Make sure you create your array in `ViewDidLoad` rather than somewhere like `ViewDidAppear` (which may be too late in the view lifecycle).

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows:

```
// main_data = Store your JSON array as "array of dictionaries"
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do as follows:

```
NSDictionary *obj = [main_data objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
// Access values as follows:
[obj objectForKey: @"Id1"]
[obj objectForKey: @"lat"]
...
...
```

Comment: I made some progress using Robotic suggestion. I have one more piece of the puzzle and I updated the question above. Please check it.