# TableView cellForRowAtIndexPath too many if statements

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, if-statement, cell

My tableviewcell has around 64 elements (32 buttons and 32 images). Each one is small (29*29) and they are stacked like a calendar so they fit within a (320*200) view. When the view first loads with the code below it works PERFECTLY! Then when you scroll down and scroll back up some of the first elements/last couple of elements get messed up. Some of the images done load, etc. I am assuming it's because there are 36 if statements running everytime the cell is loaded and that can probably cause some issues. What can I do so this does not happen any more? Can I shrink these if statements into only a couple? Thanks!

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"scheduleDaysTableViewCell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath");

        // Configure the cell...

        PFObject *object = self.octoberArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row];

        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        self.tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

        UIButton *date1Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:719];
        UIButton *date2Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:729];
        UIButton *date3Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:739];
        UIButton *date4Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:749];
        UIButton *date5Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:19];
        UIButton *date6Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:29];
        UIButton *date7Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:39];
        UIButton *date8Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:49];
        UIButton *date9Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:59];
        UIButton *date10Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:69];
        UIButton *date11Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:79];
        UIButton *date12Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:89];
        UIButton *date13Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:99];
        UIButton *date14Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:109];
        UIButton *date15Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:119];
        UIButton *date16Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:129];
        UIButton *date17Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:139];
        UIButton *date18Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:149];
        UIButton *date19Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:159];
        UIButton *date20Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:169];
        UIButton *date21Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:179];
        UIButton *date22Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:189];
        UIButton *date23Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:199];
        UIButton *date24Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:209];
        UIButton *date25Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:219];
        (...)
        UIButton *date36Button = (UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:329];

        UIImageView *date1Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:718];
        UIImageView *date2Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:728];
        UIImageView *date3Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:738];
        UIImageView *date4Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:748];
        UIImageView *date5Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:18];
        UIImageView *date6Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:28];
        UIImageView *date7Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:38];
        UIImageView *date8Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:48];
        UIImageView *date9Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:58];
        UIImageView *date10Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:68];
        UIImageView *date11Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:78];
        UIImageView *date12Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:88];
        UIImageView *date13Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:98];
        UIImageView *date14Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:108];
        UIImageView *date15Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:118];
        UIImageView *date16Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:128];
        UIImageView *date17Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:138];
        UIImageView *date18Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:148];
        UIImageView *date19Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:158];
        UIImageView *date20Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:168];
        UIImageView *date21Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:178];
        UIImageView *date22Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:188];
        UIImageView *date23Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:198];
        UIImageView *date24Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:208];
        UIImageView *date25Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:218];
        (...)
        UIImageView *date36Image = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:328];


        NSString *Date1 = object[@"Date1"];
        NSString *Date2 = object[@"Date2"];
        NSString *Date3 = object[@"Date3"];
        NSString *Date4 = object[@"Date4"];
        NSString *Date5 = object[@"Date5"];
        NSString *Date6 = object[@"Date6"];
        NSString *Date7 = object[@"Date7"];
        NSString *Date8 = object[@"Date8"];
        NSString *Date9 = object[@"Date9"];
        NSString *Date10 = object[@"Date10"];
        NSString *Date11 = object[@"Date11"];
        NSString *Date12 = object[@"Date12"];
        NSString *Date13 = object[@"Date13"];
        NSString *Date14 = object[@"Date14"];
        NSString *Date15 = object[@"Date15"];
        NSString *Date16 = object[@"Date16"];
        NSString *Date17 = object[@"Date17"];
        NSString *Date18 = object[@"Date18"];
        NSString *Date19 = object[@"Date19"];
        NSString *Date20 = object[@"Date20"];
        NSString *Date21 = object[@"Date21"];
        NSString *Date22 = object[@"Date22"];
        NSString *Date23 = object[@"Date23"];
        NSString *Date24 = object[@"Date24"];
        NSString *Date25 = object[@"Date25"];
       (...)
        NSString *Date36 = object[@"Date36"];


        //This is where I am separating the number from the word.
        NSString *date1 = [[Date1 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date2 = [[Date2 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date3 = [[Date3 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date4 = [[Date4 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date5 = [[Date5 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date6 = [[Date6 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date7 = [[Date7 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date8 = [[Date8 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date9 = [[Date9 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date10 = [[Date10 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date11 = [[Date11 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date12 = [[Date12 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date13 = [[Date13 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date14 = [[Date14 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date15 = [[Date15 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date16 = [[Date16 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date17 = [[Date17 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date18 = [[Date18 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date19 = [[Date19 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date20 = [[Date20 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date21 = [[Date21 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date22 = [[Date22 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date23 = [[Date23 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date24 = [[Date24 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *date25 = [[Date25 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        (...)
        NSString *date36 = [[Date36 componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];


        if ([Date1 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date1Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date1Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date1 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date1Button setTitle:date1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date1Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date1Button setTitle:date1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date1Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date2 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date2Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date2Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date2 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date2Button setTitle:date2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date2Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date2Button setTitle:date2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date2Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date3 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date3Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date3Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date3 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date3Button setTitle:date3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date3Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date3Button setTitle:date3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date3Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date4 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date4Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date4Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date4 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date4Button setTitle:date4 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date4Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date4Button setTitle:date4 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date4Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date5 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date5Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date5Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date5 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date5Button setTitle:date5 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date5Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date5Button setTitle:date5 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date5Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date6 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date6Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date6Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date6 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date6Button setTitle:date6 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date6Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date6Button setTitle:date6 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date6Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date7 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date7Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date7Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date7 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date7Button setTitle:date7 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date7Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date7Button setTitle:date7 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date7Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date8 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date8Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date8Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date8 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date8Button setTitle:date8 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date8Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date8Button setTitle:date8 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date8Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date9 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date9Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date9Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date9 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date9Button setTitle:date9 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date9Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date9Button setTitle:date9 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date9Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date10 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date10Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date10Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date10 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date10Button setTitle:date10 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date10Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date10Button setTitle:date10 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date10Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date11 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date11Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date11Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date11 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date11Button setTitle:date11 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date11Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date11Button setTitle:date11 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date11Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date12 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date12Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date12Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date12 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date12Button setTitle:date12 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date12Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date12Button setTitle:date12 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date12Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date13 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date13Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date13Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date13 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date13Button setTitle:date13 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date13Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date13Button setTitle:date13 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date13Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date14 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date14Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date14Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date14 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date14Button setTitle:date14 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date14Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date14Button setTitle:date14 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date14Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date15 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date15Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date15Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date15 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date15Button setTitle:date15 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date15Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date15Button setTitle:date15 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date15Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date16 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date16Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date16Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date16 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date16Button setTitle:date16 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date16Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date16Button setTitle:date16 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date16Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date17 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date17Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date17Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date17 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date17Button setTitle:date17 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date17Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date17Button setTitle:date17 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date17Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date18 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date18Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date18Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date18 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date18Button setTitle:date18 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date18Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date18Button setTitle:date18 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date18Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date19 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date19Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date19Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date19 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date19Button setTitle:date19 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date19Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date19Button setTitle:date19 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date19Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date20 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date20Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date20Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date20 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date20Button setTitle:date20 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date20Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date20Button setTitle:date20 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date20Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date21 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date21Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date21Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date21 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date21Button setTitle:date21 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date21Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date21Button setTitle:date21 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date21Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date22 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date22Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date22Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date22 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date22Button setTitle:date22 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date22Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date22Button setTitle:date22 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date22Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date23 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date23Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date23Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date23 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date23Button setTitle:date23 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date23Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date23Button setTitle:date23 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date23Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date24 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date24Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date24Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date24 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date24Button setTitle:date24 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date24Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date24Button setTitle:date24 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date24Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

        if ([Date25 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date25Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date25Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date25 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date25Button setTitle:date25 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date25Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date25Button setTitle:date25 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date25Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }

  (...)
        if ([Date36 isEqual:@"0"]) {
            //Alpha 0
            [date36Button setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date36Image.alpha = 0.0;
        } else if ([Date36 containsString:@"GREY"]) {
            //Grey
            [date36Button setTitle:date36 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date36Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"greyLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        } else {
            //Gold
            [date36Button setTitle:date36 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            date36Image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"goldLittleCircleForCalendar.png"];
        }


        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: try to use custom tableViewCell and NSMutable Array with NSDictionary

Comment: Awesome! Would you mind maybe posting some sample code and more details in an answer? @Sushrita

Comment: ok  I am posting an example in the answer

Comment: Did you check the example in the answer?

Comment: First of all, consider using for loops. Second, think of it this way: you are reusing a cell, so for example: If you have a table view with 11 cells out of which 10 are displayed, when the 11th cell will be displayed it will reuse the cell that gone off-screen (cell 0). If you do not update the content on it (for cell 10), it will reuse what was set previously (for cell 0).

Answer (score 0):

Example For reducing the code :

For Custom tableViewCell
in CustomTableViewCell.h

```
   @interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {


UIButton *button;
UIImageView *imageView;

}

 @property (nonatomic) UIButton *button;
@property (nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;
@end
```

in CustomTableViewCell.m file

```
@implementation CustomTableViewCell



@synthesize button, imageView;

 - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {


    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 1, 44, 42)];

    [self.contentView addSubview:imageView];

    distance = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    distance = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 6,225, 18)];
  //  distance.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    distance.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0];
    distance.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:distance];

}

 return self;
```

}

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
// Initialization code
 }

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

   // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

@end

Use it in tableView:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView2 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"cell";

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView2 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[SearchTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 48) reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
 return cell
 }
```

And for using NSDictionary and NSMutableArray Follow this link :
[How to populate tableView using NSDictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188495/populate-tableview-from-nsdictionary)